# Is there any change in time complexity if I can reduce the number of times the code loops by half

Tags: time-complexity

I'm wondering if I can reduce the time complexity (Big O notation) for a string reverse function if I do in place swaps instead of looping through every character in the array.

I initially thought yes because doing in place swaps I only have to loop through half of the characters in a given string. Although on second thought that would give a time complexity of O(.5n) which would equal O(n) as with asymptotic complexity we ignore multipliers.

```java
public static String reverse(String str) {

    char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()/2; i++) {

        char temp = strArray[str.length() - i - 1];
        strArray[str.length() - i - 1] = strArray[i];
        strArray[i] = temp;
    }

    return new String(strArray);
}
```

I may have answered my own question as I believe this will be the same time complexity as if I looped through every character in the string i.e. O(n), but maybe I missed something and I just wanted some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did indeed answer your own question. Cutting the time in half for all inputs does not change the theoretical time complexity. Theoretical time complexity simply measures how much the time to run grows as the input gets larger and larger. And the code you have still takes twice as long with an input that is twice as long (hence, it's `O(n)`).